# Controller coming back unauthorised even though token been verified

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Hi i am adding jwt token based auth and am still having trouble when the user requests the token and then gets authorised to make a call. I have checked it on jwt.io but its valid when i place my secret key there.

So am not sure what else could be.

Here is my code.

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult CreateToken([FromBody] LoginModel login) {
        IActionResult response = Unauthorized();
        var user = Authenticate(login);

        if (user != null) {
            var tokenString = BuildToken(login);
            response = Ok(new { token = tokenString });
        }

        return response;

 }
```

This is how I am building up my token

```
 private string BuildToken(LoginModel login) {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["JwtToken:SecretKey"]));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        JwtSecurityToken token;

            token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["JwtToken:Issuer"],
          _config["JwtToken:Issuer"], expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
          signingCredentials: creds); 
        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
 }
```

When i check the get call it comes back still unathorised even though I authorised it using swagger? and using the response from the token call?

[image]

**Edit 2**
I am still getting 401 even when i add the following.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

> Code  Details 401 Undocumented Error: Response headers  date: Fri, 22
>   May 2020 22:36:30 GMT   server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0   status: 401
>   www-authenticate: Bearer   x-powered-by: ASP.NET

**Edit 3**

I should state I am using the swagger Ui to pass the barrier token in through the standard method. 
      c.AddSecurityDefinition("bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
      {             Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.",
                });

I have a felling that this is not getting passed onto my header as it should do?.
[image]

Comment: your curl request does not have authentication header, try it on postman maybe?

Comment: I'm confused.  Your example shows you doing a GET but your controller is for a POST for a different endpoint.

Comment: @mkavici I am using swagger and want to make sure it works

Comment: @possum thats how swagger works u post with ur username and password then it returns the results